# Installed Java 7, but terminal still shows Java 6

Tags: java, osx-lion

I've installed Java 7 on my Mac (10.7.5), but in the terminal there is still java 6.

> java version "1.6.0_37"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

There will be no problem with the version 6 on terminal, if I always got that errors when I tried to install a java application ([LatexDraw](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/download.html)):

> : CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
>
> : CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0

The problem is related to instability of java 6 inferred from [this link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/18394472#18394472)

I've read this [installed-java-7-on-mac-osx-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757558/installed-java-7-on-mac-osx-but-terminal-is-still-using-version-6) and also try to change my Java version by using `export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home"`, but in my folder `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`, there is no version 1.7, only versions under 1.6 ??? So, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Java 6 on OS X Lion is Apple's version. Uninstall every version and then install Java 7

Comment: So you're essentially asking where Java 7 was installed to?

Comment: ya, a part of my question